# Algorithm: Find minimum value such that the value does not become less than 1 while iterating over an array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given an array with positive and negative integers.

Find the minimum value of 'x' such that while iterating over each element of the array:

Condition : `x = x + A[i]` and  `x` is greater than one

For example:

`A = [-2,3,1,-5]`, `x` should be 4

- Iteration 1: `A[1] = -2`, so `x` will be `4 - 2 = 2`
- Iteration 2: `A[2] = 3`, so `x` will be `2 + 3 = 5`
- Iteration 3: `A[3] = 1`, so `x` will be `5 + 1 = 6`
- Iteration 4: `A[4] = -5`, so `x` will be `6 - 5 = 1`.

Hence `x=4` is the minimum value which will hold the condition.

Comment: For example:
A= [-2,3,1,-5]  x should be 4
Iteration 1: A[1] = -2, so x will be 4 - 2 = 2
Iteration 2: A[2] =  3, so x will be 2 + 3 = 5
Iteration 3: A[3] =  1, so x will be 5 + 1 = 6
Iteration 4: A[4] = -5, so x will be 6 - 5 = 1

Hence x=4 is the minimum value which will hold the condition.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `x is greater than one` and in iteration `4`=> `6 - 5 = 1`. Can you be more clear?

Comment: @cod3rpm Question is not clear. Can you add more cases and explain it better?

Answer (score 0):

Keep prefix sum of array not less than 1-x.

```
1-min(prefix(i)) , 1 <= i <= length
```

BTW try it yourself first.